# Cypress default date is not changing

Tags: date, testing, cypress, end-to-end

my site sets cookie expiry date 7 days from current login.
i need to test cookie expiry date from cypress.
but i can't change default time of cypress i.e. 1970 Jan to current system date in cypress as it sets cookie expiry date to 1970's.
how to do that in cypress.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet? I think I know what to do but I need to see what you have done.

Comment: @NANfan, i think cookie testing doesn't lie in  e2e testing, so it is removed now